# At using two Inner Joins, it pull out just 5 rows out of the hundreds of row I should get

Tags: sql, sqlite

h.hour column should give me the number of days each b.name has but it gives me random numbers. The maximum number of days counted I should get is 7 based on the days of the week but in the only five rows the statement is pulling out I'm getting 20, 14, etc.

````
Select b.Name
    ,Sum (b.review_count) As TotalReviews
    ,Strftime ('%Y',r.date) As Year
    ,Count (r.text) As WrittenReviews
    ,Count (h.Hours)
    ,Case
        When b.Is_Open = 1 Then 'Open'
        Else 'Close'
    End IsItOpen
From business b
    Inner Join review r On r.business_id = b.id
    Inner Join Hours h On b.id = h.business_id
Group By b.name
Order By TotalReviews DESC```
````

Comment: To help we'd need to see the schema for the tables, a sample of data which shows the problem, and the result you expect. If you're getting 'random numbers' from `h.hours` that suggests the table does not contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Count (h.Hours) -> Sum (h.Hours)

The SQLite count function returns the count of an expression.